# Texmaker won't start and uses a lot of CPU

Tags: texmaker, texworks

I have recently installed `texmaker` and `texworks`, because I would like to write my thesis with it. However after a week or so I started to experience a lot of problems.

Now it came to the point that I can't open any files with `texmaker` *("file not found")*, and the ones that are possible to open cannot be quickbuilt. Beside that, when I start `texmaker` my computer gets very loud and the programm uses almost half of my CPU power *(I actually have a very new and rather good comput)*.

I wanted to ask if anyone encountered the same problems or knows a solution to my problem?

Thanks in advance, any help highly appreciated

Comment: Hi and welcome. In my opinion your computer is infected, you must have a virus, disinfect it.

Comment: I think this is highly unlikely. My computer only shows this weird kind of behaviour when using texmaker

Comment: What version of Windows do you have?

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: Me too and I don't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my entire PhD thesis with `LaTeX`. I had trouble at the very beginning which was solved by changing from `Miktex` to `TexLive` and using `Texstudio` instead of `Texmaker`.

There is nothing technical but only sharing my own experience.

Maybe you also don't need two softwares as `TexWorks` and `Texmaker` do pretty much the same.

Regarding the CPU, compiling a large document may require a lot of ressource. The more recent your processor, the faster it will be. It could also be useful to switch off all other softwares while compiling.

If the files are not found, maybe you could check whether your files (especially the ones you call with the `\include{path/file}` command, are correctly set in the proper folders.

Hope that can help you solve this issue.

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment. I thought texworks and texmaker was needed for functioning properly

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score -1):

You could try [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com) It is an online latex editor. It compiles latex documents on its own and shows you the output.